# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk configuration – non-built-in php.ini configs

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-ini

I am deploying an app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, and their docs list a namespace in `.ebextensions` that can be used for setting the PHP.ini configuration:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.container.html

The namespace is `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini`.

I assumed that it was possible to add any PHP configuration, for instance `disable_functions` (a core PHP.ini directive), but it looks like this is impossible, and only some pre-determined configuration options are supported. EBS throws an error that the option is not supported.

How can I set additional PHP configurations in Amazon EBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best way to do this is to use .ebextensions to add a new ini file that will be read by the PHP that EB installs. For example:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/99-disable-functions.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      disable_functions = exec,shell_exec,passthru,proc_open,system,parse_ini_file,show_source
```